# Why do I only sometimes get "type instantiation too deep" error?

Tags: typescript

I'm actually currently trying to write an article on the "type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" TS error. I'm having a really hard time reproducing this error.

I've taken some code from my package [`that-routing-lib`](https://github.com/MatthiasvB/that-routing-lib/blob/main/src/that-routing-lib.ts) and removed an artificial depth limiter for a recursive type analysis to get the error. But I realized I do not understand this well enough to write about it.

The following code is broken down really really far from the original problem, but I think it's the root of why I need to limit my recursive mapped type in the first place. I do not understand why I don't get the error in the `extract` function, but do in `extract2`:

(the function bodies make no sense of course. It's only about the types)

```js
type Recursive = { [key: string]: Recursive } | Record<string, string>

type ExtractKeys<T> = keyof T | (T extends object ? ExtractKeys<T[keyof T]> : never)

function extract<T extends Recursive>(proto: T): ExtractKeys<T> {
    return 'ho' as ExtractKeys<T>;
    // no error
};

function extract2<T extends Recursive>(proto: T): ExtractKeys<T>[] {
    return ['ho'] as ExtractKeys<T>[];
    //     ~~~~~~ <- Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGBXATgZwJYDdoF4oG8oBtAawhAC4pVhl0A7AcwF0q4k0toBfKAH1gIA9sgAmAHhp0mAGmq0GjAHwAoFaEhQAogA9aAQ3jAA0uVTiAKkqh4yIIQDMoF-lAAULiHoj1RqKEIARgBWCMBQAPzaesiGJmaWpOSOzszWVPQQ2MgAlGoOiPRG6EL0UF4GRpbl3r7+7CgY2EpuYMhCwEJUFjlUupXxIOZWBCpQ41DIEMAoZQDkABZCc1D6-v2xRqZDlkoA3CrcByoFRcAlZRWbwABM1RU+foIcTRAtbR1dzr3RA9vDSiIzFGE0m01mxEWy2Ba1+13+uyBByOQA)

Any advice that helps me figure out TS type analysis works here, and why it breaks (in only one case) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I presume the answer to this depends on implementation details of the compiler, but I'm not particularly inclined to go diving too deeply searching for this, since it's necessarily at the edges of supportable behavior.  Subscribed though to see if anyone else has something interesting to say about it